# Direct Trustee IRA transfer

Tags: united-states, income-tax, ira

In March 2019, I did a Direct Trustee Transfer from Fidelity IRA (cash account) to a Ally Bank IRA CD.  Neither institution has sent any tax paperwork for this.  Does this need to be reported on my 1040?

Answer (score 1):

You should have received a Form 1099-R from Fidelity for this rollover. The amount would go on Form 1040, line 4a, but the taxable amount (line 4b) should be $0 so it won't affect your taxes owed. Still, you probably want to check with Fidelity to see why you have received a 1099 yet (it should have been sent by the end of January).

Comment: I just called Fidelity.  They said that a 1099-R was not sent because there was nothing which was tax reportable.  They sent the all the funds DIRECTLY to Ally who then put it in a IRA CD.

Comment: @ironv Very strange; I have done many non-taxable rollovers with Fidelity and have always gotten a 1099-R.

Comment: I _think_ this may be covered under https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1099r.pdf page 6 (under __Transfers__).  "Generally, do not report a transfer between trustees or issuers that involves no payment or distribution of funds to the participant, including a trustee-to-trustee transfer from one IRA to another IRA, "

Comment: @ironv Interesting, I have always gotten 1099-Rs in these situations. However, they always seem to need to mail me a check (though not made out directly to me), and have me mail it to the receiving brokerage (even rolling a Fidelity IRA into a Fidelity 401k, believe it or not). I guess if your rollover was purely trustee-to-trustee, that's why a 1099-R was not issued.